# How to avoid anchor tag click without #

Tags: html, click, anchor

I avoided PageRefresh on anchor tag click by adding # in href. But this makes my page move up. How can I stope Page Refresh without adding #?

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#LevelDropdown_@priorityProvider.Provider.ProviderId@uniqueLeadSourcePriorityId"></a>
```

Comment: Why are you using an `<a>` if you don't want to link somewhere? Use a `<button type="button">` instead.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for the advice. Will be using button tag

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery function to prevent refresh page on anchor click

```
    $(function(){
      $("a").click(function()
      {
        $.get("YourUrl" );
        return false; // prevent browser to refresh
      });
    });
```